# Prevent AJAX calls from firing twice everytime

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a web application using JQuery 3.3.1. It would seem that everytime I make ajax call, the request is sent twice. I can tell because I tried logging the requests on server side. I tried solutions from similar questions but they do not seem to help.

I separated the ajax call from click events, so it does not happen because of click event being registered twice.

```
$(function() {
    console.log("hi");

    var request = {};
    request["user_id"] = 1;
    request["date"] = new Date();
    request["assignments"] = [{
        "point_count" : 1,
        "skill_mnemo" : "SKILL_FARM"
    }];

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            mimeType: "application/json",
            url: "./api/update_skill_point.php",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: request,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your original code here? where is the click event

Comment: ajax call is under IFFE function i.e. self executed function when it loads into browser. So its not the part of any event.

Comment: `$(function() {});` is not IIFE thought. It is not parsed immediately it is parsed when the DOM is ready

Comment: Check the request method of both the requests, First One might be a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Answer (score 1):

You have to debug this code by the following ways:

1. Check how many times `hii` is printing into console.
2. Add break point at start of `$.ajax`. Then check the call stack.
3. Check into network tab and analyse the call stack at initiator column for the corresponding ajax call.(for Chrome)

Hope it will help for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
1. It's only printed once
2. In call stack it seems that the function is only called once

Comment: Then go to network tab and check the call stack at initiator column for the corresponding ajax call.(for Chrome)

Comment: Well this moved us somewhere. Until now I was testing in Mozilla Firefox Developer build. After your suggestion I tried doing the same in Chrome and the event only fired once

Comment: Oddly enough, in the mentioned Firefox response code is 200(okay), response in success function is the one it is supposed to be, but in network tab the response code is 200 and response contains error content, plus the call is logged twice

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that the submit button in your form is **NOT** set to *type="button"*.
So, on-clicking the button, your ajax function runs and the browser also attempts to submit the form (default behavior of submit buttons) to your current URL. This might give the appearance that ajax is being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

don't use

```
(function(){})
```

if we use (function(){}), it will call itself when DOM is getting ready and then again when required.

Try

```
function ajaxCall()
{
 console.log("hi");

    var request = {};
    request["user_id"] = 1;
    request["date"] = new Date();
    request["assignments"] = [{
        "point_count" : 1,
        "skill_mnemo" : "SKILL_FARM"
    }];

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            mimeType: "application/json",
            url: "./api/update_skill_point.php",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: request,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
    });
}

$(document).ready(){
 ajaxCall();
}
```

In this way you can control your ajax call,
Now you might have some idea how to deal, if not let me know, I'll try to explain more.

Comment: Well, to use debugger, I had to move the code to a function in a separate file and then call it as you suggest.

But is there a difference between `(function(){})` and `$( document ).ready(function() {})` ? From what I see on JQuery page, _developers sometimes use the shorthand $() for $( document ).ready()_. Aren't those the same thing then?
Plus I think your syntax in the last three lines is not correct

Comment: `(function(){})` will not be automatically executed. But `(function(){})()` will.

Comment: @nortander - That's right, `$(fn)` and `$(document).ready(fn)` will both execute `fn()` function when the DOM is ready. (But do not forget `$` before `(fn)`)

Comment: @iArcadia I think I understand what you mean. But I am not sure what Dupinder is suggesting

Comment: I was also trying to say same thing as @iArcadia wants to say, But yaa i agree my last 3 lines may be worng, I was trying to give an idea.

Comment: @DupinderSingh Yeah, sorry, I didn't mean to be petty. I'm just not quite sure what's the difference between my code and yours